# Escape character for space after \n

Tags: javascript

I have a string:

```
'\n Hello'
```

which adds an empty line before 'Hello'. However, since I have a space after it to have it more readable for the developers, it also adds this space to the string that is visible to the users.

How can I keep the space between \n and Hello without getting the space in the output?

Comment: Don't worry about the developers. They don't need the space there for it to be readable to them. That's what they do.

Comment: When you say "it also adds this empty line", do you mean "it also adds this space"?

Comment: @MichaelMior corrected

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate strings: `'\n' + 'Hello'`